# how to benchmark DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver

Is there any web-based or desktop tool that can tell me the performance and quality of a name server? I have the option to use my ISP or my domain registar's name server, I need some help to decide.

Answer (score 1):

[NameBench by google employee](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/)

[Grc DNS Benchmark](http://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Sheer speed probably isn't the only thing you should be looking for. It's very possible that your ISP will show as better if you're testing from a connection on the ISP's network, where as your Hosting provider might have multiple servers local to various exchanges that would make their DNS servers faster over all!

Are the DNS servers in different separate network segments? Are they using technologies like Anycast/Heartbeat to ensure redundancy? What's the management interface like? What kind of monitoring do they have?

It's relatively easy to set-up DNS servers like Bind, NSD, PowerDNS etc. these days to be very fast on benchmarks like given by Madboy, but there's lots of other factors to consider as well.

Comment: How can I find out more about the things you mentioned? redundancy

Comment: what do you guys think of http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/?

Comment: The only way you can really find out about the redundancy is to ask them or check to see if it's documented on their site. Google's Public DNS is primarily for resolving DNS, not for hosting you own domains. Can I confirm whether you're looking for name servers to host your own domain name (Authoritative DNS) or just name servers to point your computer at (Resolvers)?

Comment: I am using google dns mostly. It's easy to remember and I think responsivness/redundancy is ok.

Comment: the one where i can configure my domain/subdomain/mx...

Comment: what about opendns?

Comment: Are you looking to host your own domain on DNS or are you looking for general DNS server. Those 2 are different (although you could probably use them for both features).

Comment: to host my own domains

Comment: if it's to host your domains, then you need an Authoritative DNS servers. I would recommend going with your hosting provider as: 1. They probably have more experience running Authoritative DNS than your ISP who would be more concerned with Resolvers. 2. You should have the ability to manage your DNS from the same control panel as your web hosting. This means that say if you add hosting for "blog.domain.com" to your hosting package, it should be automagically added to your DNS.

Comment: my host doesn't provide a control panel. i have to email them every time. I need to find a better alternative.

Comment: There are many good authoritative DNS providers. Just to name a few: Gandi.net, Namecheap, DNSMadeEasy. Some of the just do DNS, others also register your domain for you.